# C# Youtube API, not firing events

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, youtube

I've searched up and down the internet throughout the day, and I'm just stumped.

What I want to do is play a youtube video inside of C# using the youtube API.  Then I want a function on the form to be called when the video finishes playing.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to get the events to fire.

(Using Visual C# 2010 Express, and have IE9.  For reference.)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // This nested class must be ComVisible for the JavaScript to be able to call it.
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class ScriptManager
        {
            // Variable to store the form of type Form1.
            private Form1 mForm;

            // Constructor.
            public ScriptManager(Form1 form)
            {
                // Save the form so it can be referenced later.
                mForm = form;
            }

            // This method can be called from JavaScript.
            public void MethodToCallFromScript()
            {
                // Call a method on the form.
                mForm.GoToNext();
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void GoToNext()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Play the next song");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/index.html");
        }
    }
}
```

That is my Form1.cs code.  Form1.cs [Design] consists of nothing more than a webBrowser control.

I've tried numerous things to get this to work, from installing an http server to run the html 'live' to running it from a file directly off my computer, to setting the document text with the code as a string.  All has failed me thus far.  In IE9 if I open the index.html file locally (as a file and not through my webserver) the events do not fire.  If I run it live off my webserver the events do fire.  However in C# webBrowser control, these events do not seem to fire at all, no matter where it's run from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
            videoId: 'G4cRrOcDXXY',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.mute();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
            window.external.MethodToCallFromScript();
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'd love to get events to fire in the C# WebBrowser control.

Comment: Still bashing my head on a wall over this.  This problem in its simplest form is that "javascript events" that you tell the youtube player to subscribe to do not work.  eg, "onReady" never happens in my C# webBrowser.  The video should start muted, but this does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  I was in the process of typing out my newest problem when I attempted something else with great success.  The problem **was** that I'd navigate to my .html file on my webserver, and it'd begin playing a video, when the video finished, I'd have javascript tell C# to navigate to the same URL with a different youtube ID (to play another video).  The second video would fail to fire the events.

I've overcome this by using different javascript, such as [what was mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128910/youtube-js-api-breaking-change-will-no-longer-initialize-without-the-videoid-pa).

I did start using Visual Studio 2013 Express, and IE11.  That cleared up quite a few problems I was bumping into on it's own.  I'll provide you guys with my current code, just in case anyone ever runs into the issues I've been dealing with.

My form:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // This nested class must be ComVisible for the JavaScript to be able to call it.
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class ScriptManager
        {
            // Variable to store the form of type Form1.
            private Form1 mForm;

            // Constructor.
            public ScriptManager(Form1 form)
            {
                // Save the form so it can be referenced later.
                mForm = form;
            }

            public void AnotherMethod(string message)
            {
                mForm.GoToNext();
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void GoToNext()
        {
            timer1.Interval = 2000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public object MyInvokeScript(string name, params object[] args)
        {
            return webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(name, args);
        }
        public void SongCheck()
        {
            // Disable timer.  Enable it later if there isn't a song to play.
            if (timer1.Enabled)
            timer1.Enabled = false;

            // Connect to my SQLite db,
            SQLiteConnection mySQLite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ytsongrequest.s3db;Version=3;");
            mySQLite.Open();

            // The SQLite DB consists of three columns. id, youtubeid, requestor
            // the 'id' auto increments when a row is added into the database.
            string sqlCommand = "select * from songs order by id asc limit 1";
            SQLiteCommand x = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCommand, mySQLite);

            SQLiteDataReader reader = x.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Use our custom object to call a javascript function on our webpage.
                    object o = MyInvokeScript("createPlayerAndPlayVideo", reader["youtubeid"]);
                    label2.Text = reader["requestor"].ToString();
                    // Since we've played the song, we can now remove it.
                    x = new SQLiteCommand("delete from songs where id = " + reader["id"], mySQLite);
                    x.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                mySQLite.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // Set a timer to check for a new song every 10 seconds.
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptManager(this);
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/testing.html");

            GoToNext();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SongCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML page that I have on my server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);

var player;
var playerAPIReady;



function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    playerAPIReady = true;
}


function onPlayerReady() {
    player.playVideo();
    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
    if (e.data === 0) {
        window.external.AnotherMethod('Finished video');
    }
    });
}

function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

function createPlayerAndPlayVideo(id) {
    if(! playerAPIReady) {
        // player API file not loaded
        return;
    }
    if (! player) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: id,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
        player.loadVideoById(id);
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```